# how to scrape all the links of image of product present in flipkart

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** url of all the different images present in this link https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-nxt-gold-32-gb/p/itmemzd4gepexjya?pid=MOBEMZD4KHRF5VZX. I am trying it with beautifulsoup module of python. but didn't succeed with this method. I am not able to understand the code structure of flipkart.com and why it is not returning the required data.
The code that I am trying is as follow

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from pprintpp import pprint
import pandas as pd
import requests
from time import sleep

x=requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-nxt-gold-32-gb/p/itmemzd4gepexjya?pid=MOBEMZD4KHRF5VZX").content
#x= urllib._urlopener("https://www.flipkart.com/jbl-t250si-on-the-ear-headphone/p/itmefbgezsc72mgt?pid=ACCEFBGAK5ZDTBF7&")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')
data=[]
for j in soup2.find_all('img', attrs={'class':"sfescn"}):
    data+=[j]
    print data
```

Comment: can you please show us your code ?

Comment: Please show what you tried so far ?

Comment: I think you are only getting 2 image links. Right ?

Comment: this code is returning nothing, no link at all

Comment: did you print `x` ? shouldn't be `x.text` ?

Comment: did you check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add images ?

Answer (score 4):

Well I can clearly see that there are no links of mobile images in the page source code.
So I would recommend using tool Fiddler or your browser developer's console to track where the actual data is coming from, most probably it would be coming from a json response type request.
I am not familiar with beautifulsoup, i have been working with scrapy.